# Looking for a theme recommendation for flexible content region?

Tags: 7, theming

I am looking for a theme whose content region automatically expands to fill the sidebar regions when those shrink. ie the content region and sidebars must be in the same container with the content region designed to expand to fill the sidebar regions when those shrink. It is mainly to free the space taken up by the elements and menu in the sidebar when during editing content I don't need them, but call them out when I do. It should be a theme without wasted space and designed to use all the screen area.
I want to use the JQuery slide toggle system to expand the side bars when I need them,and shrink them when I don't.

e.g. I currently have [Admin](http://drupal.org/project/admin) doing something similar but it shifts the whole page and has its own menu style. I want the header and footer areas intact and just the content area expanded and contracted as required.

I just want to load up Firebug and adjust the sidebar widths and if the content region expands or contracts to fill the space or shrinks I'll be happy to apply my JQuery.

Comment: disable regions and put blocks of sidebars in content region. Fix the region with CSS. Eg: How you fix the image to left right in some articles and the article continue to fill other space after the image.

Comment: I asked this question because of virtually zero knowledge of CSS. I was even going to state in the question that I didn't want any CSS suggestions, just a ready made theme with this capability built in, but decide that against that because I thought it wouldn't be well received. Perhaps I should edit the question and put that it back in.

Comment: I don't think there is ready made solutions like that (I might be wrong), but generally Drupal Theme creator tries to satisfy the default Drupal theming configs like `page top`, `page bottom`, `first sidebar`, `second sidebar` and most of the themes are made to accomplish this. You better try `panels` `panopoly`, or `display suite`. As for CSS its just `float:left` or `float:right` which you can learn in 10 mins and implement nicely.